# jQuery dialog: doesn't run other client side validations properly?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-dialog

From what I have played around with JQuery Dialog, I made an observation that the elements inside the dialog have some hard time trying to 'load' properly.

Scenario:

1) I clicked a button to load a dialog.

2) The dialog has a save button, a close button, and 2 textboxes, 1 which is linked to Jquery's datepicker. Another is a textbox that is [Required].

From the save button, I have the behavior of:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#EventManage");
```

It seems that:

1) The datepicker doesn't work instantly. Instead I have to close the dialog, and open it a few times in order to make it work.

2) If I click save, and the validation sometimes doesn't work at all. It takes a close of the dialog a few times to make it work as well, sometimes.

3) If that validation works by showing an error, the datepicker no longer works.

4) on the first run, the dialog seems to take a pretty long time to load.

Any ideas why is the behavior so strange?

**EDIT**

Firebug showing me stuff:-

DateTime:-
i is undefined  function(f){f=a(f.target).closest("but...d("a").removeClass("ui-state-hover");

Button not able to pass through any validation nor submit form:-
$.validator.unobtrusive    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#EventManage");

Clicking any textbox and then clicking elsewhere:-
c.validator.methods[e] is undefined [Break On This Error] prepareElement:function(a){this.reset(...tion occured when checking element "+

**EDIT**

Seems like the cause is due to dual referencing of the js files.

The features seem to working properly. However, I am encountering the datepicker showing but unable to pick any date at all. Any ideas? :)

**EDIT 3**

I think I found the issue. I have a datepicker setDefaults that sets the date to maxdate:0 in my main layout. Now i am setting the datepicker within the dialog's partial cshtml to be minDate: 1. how do i override the layout's datepicker?

**SOLVED:** just need to set maxDate: null. phew!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you update the DOM and replace the corresponding input field of the datepicker, the same way you are reattaching the unobtrusive client side validation, you should re-attach the datepicker: `$('.datepicker').datepicker();`.

Comment: hi Darin, is this done during the button clicks? Or on the dialog load? Or when? I am having issues when the dialog first loads.

Comment: I checked with FireBug and I got this error when I first clicked the datepicker:

i is undefined
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js
Line 275

Comment: Another error spotted: 

$.validator.unobtrusive is undefined
http://localhost:18186/home/homepage
Line 307

$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#EventManage");

Comment: And another. hmm

c.validator.methods[e] is undefined
[Break On This Error] prepareElement:function(a){this.reset(...tion occured when checking element "+

Comment: @RicL, have you included the correct scripts? jquery-ui? jquery.validate? jquery.validate.unobtrusive? Have you verified that those scripts exist? Have you verified that you are not getting some other errors when referencing them? The fact that you are getting a `datepicker undefined error` strongly suggests that you haven't properly referenced jquery ui. Showing your full source code could also help diagnose the problem. Right now we can only be guessing here.

Comment: Just a quick question @Darin, those referenced scripts should be included inside the dialog's partial page? or from the main page?

Comment: Would there be an issue if the items are referenced twice on both the dialog's layout and the main layout? I start to suspect this might be the cause of the issue..?

Comment: @RicL, normally scripts are included only once, ideally before the closing `</body>` tag. You could place a section inside your _Layout that will be overriden in the view in order to include required scripts. No scripts should be included in any partial.